# OWL API Storing a local copy of an ontology opened through url

Tags: android, file, owl-api

I'm working with OWL API 3.4.10 in Android. 
I'm trying to store a local copy of an ontology which I opened using its URL.

After opening the ontology via URL, I try to save it with this method:

```
public void saveLocalCopy(OWLOntology o, String filename, String path) throws OWLOntologyStorageException,OWLOntologyCreationException, IOException {
    String extension = ".owl";
    File file = new File(path+filename+extension);

    file.createNewFile();
    manager.saveOntology(o, IRI.create(file));
    file.delete();
 }
```

When I try to open it from the specified path, I get this exception:

```
   com.example.user.myproject W/System.err: org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyInputSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ontology.owl (No such file or directory)
```

How could I manage this? 
p.s.: the read/write permissions in the Manifest are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: file.delete();  =>  FileNotFoundException when try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `file.delete()` on the file that contains the ontology you just saved. That's unlikely to be what you want to be.